# Recursive `setTimeout` doesn't engage in expected way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, mobx

I have a range input field with a numeric value which changes when I drag:

[image]

When I drag all the way to the right, the max value of the input increases. Then, when I release (onMouseUp or onTouchEnd), the max value decreases so that I can drag further and continue increasing max by dragging:

[image]

When I drag all the way to the left, the min value of the input decreases. Then, when I release (onMouseUp or onTouchEnd), the min value increases so that I can drag further and continue decreasing min by dragging:

[image]

I should always have a range of 99. For example, if I have increased the max value to 530, the min value will be 431.

**PROBLEM:**

I have two recursive `setTimeout`s set for the `min` and `max` values changing.

When the user first drags all the way to either side, the number should slowly change. If they hold it for 2 seconds, the number should increase more quickly. Relevant code:

```
// After arbitrary period, increase the rate at which the max value increments
this.fasterChangeStake = setTimeout(() => {
  this.stakeChangeTimeout = this.FAST_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT;
}, 2000);
```

This works the first time. But subsequent times, it latches onto the faster timeout first:

[image]

This is despite my clearing of timeouts when the drag ends:

```
clearTimeout(this.increaseStakeLimits);
clearTimeout(this.decreaseStakeLimits);
clearTimeout(this.timer);
```

Why is the first (slower) timeout not engaging?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/NgjKMa?editors=0010

JS:

```
const {observable, action} = mobx
const {observer} = mobxReact
const {Component} = React

@observer
class InputRange extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.INITIAL_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT = 200;
    this.FAST_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT = 20;
    this.SNAP_PERCENT = 10;
    this.increaseStakeLimits = this.increaseStakeLimits.bind(this);
    this.decreaseStakeLimits = this.decreaseStakeLimits.bind(this);
  }

  @observable min = 0;
  @observable max = 99;
  @observable stakeChangeTimeout = this.INITIAL_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT;
  @observable isIncreasing = false;
  @observable isDecreasing = false;
  @observable stake = 0;
  @action updateStake = (amount) => {
    if (amount > -1) {
      this.stake = amount
    }
  };

  increaseStakeLimits() {
    const { updateStake } = this;

    this.max = this.max += 1;
    this.min = this.max - 99
    updateStake(this.max);

    // After arbitrary period, increase the rate at which the max value increments
    this.fasterChangeStake = setTimeout(() => {
      this.stakeChangeTimeout = this.FAST_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT;
    }, 2000);

    // Recursive call, like setInterval
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.increaseStakeLimits, this.stakeChangeTimeout);
    this.isIncreasing = true;
  }

  decreaseStakeLimits() {
    console.warn('this.stake:', this.stake)
    const { stake } = this
    const { updateStake } = this;

    this.min = this.min -= 1;
    this.max = this.min + 99
    updateStake(this.min);

    // After arbitrary period, increase the rate at which the max value increments
    this.fasterChangeStake = setTimeout(() => {
      this.stakeChangeTimeout = this.FAST_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT;
    }, 2000);

    // Recursive call, like setInterval
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.decreaseStakeLimits, this.stakeChangeTimeout);
    this.isDecreasing = true;

  }

  handleStakeChange = e => {
    clearTimeout(this.increaseStakeLimits);
    clearTimeout(this.decreaseStakeLimits);
    clearTimeout(this.timer);

    const { updateStake } = this;
    const { stake } = this;

    const val = Number(e.target.value)

    // User has scrolled all the way to the right
    if (val >= this.max) {
      console.warn("scrolled to right")
      this.increaseStakeLimits();

    // User has scrolled all the way to the left
    } else if (val <= this.min) {
      console.warn("scrolled to left")
      if (val > -1) {
        this.decreaseStakeLimits();
      }
    } else {
      updateStake(val);
    }
  };

  handleRelease = () => {
    console.warn("RANGE:", this.max - this.min)
    console.warn("released");
    clearTimeout(this.fasterChangeStake);
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    // Reset the timeout value to the initial one
    this.stakeChangeTimeout = this.INITIAL_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT;
    this.SNAP_PERCENT = 10
    const snapAmount = this.SNAP_PERCENT
    if (this.isIncreasing) {
      this.max += snapAmount
    }

    if(this.isDecreasing && this.min > 0) {
      this.min -= snapAmount
    }

    this.isIncreasing = false;
    this.isDecreasing = false;
  };

  render() {
    const { stake } = this;

    const style = {
      backgroundSize:
        (stake - this.min) * 100 / (this.max - this.min) + "% 100%"
    };

    return (
      <div className="rangeContainer">
        <div>{this.stake}</div>
        <div className="inputContainer">
          <input
            id="betRangeId"
            type="range"
            min={this.min}
            max={this.max}
            step="1"
            ref={input => {
              this.textInput = input;
            }}
            value={this.stake}
            onChange={this.handleStakeChange}
            onTouchEnd={this.handleRelease}
            onMouseUp={this.handleRelease}
            style={style}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputRange />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really clever UI!

`increaseStakeLimits()` fires continuously the whole time the user holds the slider to the far right, so you're continually setting new setTimeouts to change `this.stakeChangeTimeout` to the shorter interval after two seconds (and continually setting new values for `this.fasterChangeStake`).  These continue to fire even after `handleRelease()` tries to reset the interval to the longer value, which forces it back into fast mode until all of them have fired (the `clearTimeout` in `handleRelease()` only catches one of them.)

You can fix this by only setting that timeout once:

```
if (!this.fasterChangeStake) {
  this.fasterChangeStake = setTimeout(() => {
    this.stakeChangeTimeout = this.FAST_STAKE_CHANGE_TIMEOUT;
    this.fasterChangeStake = false; // <-- also do this in handleRelease() after clearing the timeout
  }, 2000);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgmMNq?editors=0010